# Sum of fields in a field update when some of the fields are null

Tags: workflow, formula, field-update

I'm using a workflow rule to populate a field with the sum of some fields.  All of the fields are in the currency type.

`Field__c + Field1__c + Field2__c`

It works perfectly if the values are populated.  If the fields are blank, which is their default value, this formula does not work and it returns a blank value.  How can I check for null properly in the formula field?

For example, if the field values are `$5.00`, `$4.00`, and  `null` I expect the sum to be `$9.00`.

I don't want to set a default value for these fields of $0.00.

Comment: Are you saying that when all fields are null you want the sum to be 0, or are you saying that if any one field is null, you are expecting a sum but are getting blank?

Comment: @D.S. That if I have field values of 5.00, 4.00 a null, I expect 9.00.

Comment: formula in a field update?

Comment: @cropredy There is a checkbox that allows you to use a formula to set a new value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your friend is the BLANKVALUE function that if the first argument is null, will use the second argument as the value of the expression

```
BLANKVALUE(Field__c,0) + BLANKVALUE(Field1__c,0) + BLANKVALUE(Field2__c,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is not ideal, you can wrap each of your field references is an `IF` statement to ensure it is not null. This would look something like:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Field1__c), 0, Field1__c) + IF(ISBLANK(Field1__c), 0, Field1__c) + ...
```

This is tedious but unfortunately there is no "Treat blank fields as 0" during workflow field updates (that I am aware of).

Comment: This definitely works, but BLANKVALUE as posted above is slightly more concise. :)